# Does a wireless repeater bridge only extend the range of the wireless signal?

Tags: wireless-networking

If I have a wireless repeater bridge, does this simply extend the range of the WiFi signal or can I also wirelessly connect to the wireless repeater i.e. modem -> wireless router -> wireless bridge -> wireless repeater -> wireless clients e.g. wireless laptop

Comment: not sure what you mean... a repeater passes whatever it gets along whether to a client or to the router. You can use it both ways. But they are dumb, so you can not do anything really with them.

Comment: Can we have the make and model of the wireless repeater?

Comment: @Logman - I am asking whether a wireless client and connect to a wireless repeater. Based on my understanding of Paul's reply below, yes it is possible.

Comment: @Dave M - I am attempting to understand the purpose of a wireless repeater and whether I can connect to it using wireless and wired clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A wireless repeated by definition extends the range of a wireless connection.  It uses wifi to both connect to another AP and also to provide AP services to whatever is in range.

As there is usually only one radio involved, then this effectively halves the throughput of the wireless device.  Any client originated packets first travel over the air to the repeated bridge, which then forwards them over the air to the headend AP.  So there are double the amount of packets in the air as compared to a simple client->AP setup.

Note that your diagram is a little off, it would look more like:

```
Wireless Clients -> Wireless Repeater -> Wireless AP (modem I think in your case)
```

Comment: So a wireless repeater would allow both wired and wireless clients to connect to it. Is that right?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey, yes that is right